# How to append text labels to their respective circles in a horizontal legend?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know this is elementary d3, but I'm having trouble appending the text of a horizontal legend's labels to the their  respective circles, such that there's a uniform space between each circle and its text label.

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g1Mt62XcIylzGb4RRnop?p=preview

Here's some of the code at issue:

```
li.selectAll("text")
    .data(items,function(d) { return d.key})
    .call(function(d) { d.enter().append("text")})
    .call(function(d) { d.exit().remove()})
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return 12+i*75})
    .attr("y","0.39em")
    .text(function(d) { ;return d.key})

li.selectAll("circle")
    .data(items,function(d) { return d.key})
    .call(function(d) { d.enter().append("circle")})
    .call(function(d) { d.exit().remove()})
    .attr("cx",function(d,i) { return i*7.1+"em"})
    .attr("cy",0)
    .attr("r","0.4em")
    .style("fill",function(d) { console.log(d.value.color);return d.value.color})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but my code at https://steeplechasers.org/membership/membership-statistics/ is doing a similar type of legend.

See https://steeplechasers.org/wp-content/themes/steeps/js/membership-stats.js and search for legend to see how this was done.

Normally I put into the code where I got this example, as I did not figure it out myself. I wish I did this time so that I can refer to the original work. Unfortunately I did not add the reference in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to adapt what you did when I get home. I might also try to steal your tooltip, too.

Comment: If this works for you, please feel free to mark the answer correct. :) Although you might consider the answer by Andrew Reid is more directly correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different spacing methods:

```
.attr("cx",function(d,i) { return i*7.1+"em"}) // every 7.1 em

.attr("x",function(d,i) { return 12+i*75})     // every 75 pixels, offset 12
```

You need to use the same multiplier, otherwise the distance between the circle and the text will vary with `i`. Try:

```
.attr("cx",function(d,i) { return i*75 })  // every 75 pixels

.attr("x",function(d,i) { return 12+i*75}) // every 75 pixels, offset 12
```

See updated [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Qf5qVkg67K3Kej8pSnZ?p=preview).